# Non-ascii characters get ignored in Godot lable text

Tags: godot

I was working on a Hello World scene of Godot.

Instead of using "Hello World" as demonstrated in the tutorial, I tried something like "你好世界", but I found that it didn't work. Anything non-ASCII that I typed in the label text input got ignored.

How can I use non-ASCII characters in Godot labels? Or is it supported at all?

Comment: Are you sure that the selected **font** for the label supports those characters?

Comment: @UNOPARATOR I've found an answer on the GoDot QA site.

Comment: @satoru Please post as an answer for those of us who are also having the same issue.

Comment: @kojow7 You have to add a font that support your target language for the label. For example: https://godotengine.org/qa/46955/how-to-change-font-of-the-label

Answer (score 1):

The default `Label` font in Godot doesn't support non-ASCII characters.

You can try to change the font in your `Label` node to one that supports non-ASCII symbols by picking a font from your computer, or if it doesn't exist on your device, uploading it from some site like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com).

After choosing the font for your `Label` node, open the `Custom Fonts` property in the editor of the node, and create a `DynamicFont`, and in `Font` => `Font Data` press `Load` and choose your font in the opened window in the file system (`.ttf` or any another font extension).